# OpenCV Reporting TBR instead of FPS when using capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ffmpeg, osx-snow-leopard

I have several videos that I am trying to process using OpenCV and Qt 4.7.4 on Mac OS 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). If I create a  `cv::VideoCapture` object and then query for the frame rate related to such video, what I get back is the TBR and not FPS.

For instance if use `ffprobe Video1.mp4` what I get is:

```
>> ffprobe Video1.mp4      
ffprobe version 0.7.8, Copyright (c) 2007-2011 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 24 2011 14:31:00 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --   
enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-
libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 
--enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --
enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Video1.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp41avc1qt  
creation_time   : 2012-01-09 23:09:43
encoder         : vlc 1.1.3 stream output
encoder-eng     : vlc 1.1.3 stream output
Duration: 00:10:10.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 800 kb/s
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p, 704x480 [PAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 798 
kb/s, 27.71 fps, 1001 tbr, 1001 tbn, 2002 tbc
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2012-01-09 23:09:43
```

Which correctly reports FPS = 27.71 and TBR = 1001. Nevertheless if I use the following OpenCV code to query for the FPS:

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                        "Open Video",
                                        "Video Files (*.mp4, *.mpg)");

capture.release();
capture.open(filename.toAscii().data());

if (!capture.isOpened()){
    qDebug() <<"Error when opening the video!";
    return;
}


qDebug() << "Frame Rate:" << capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
qDebug() << "Num of Frames:" << capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
qDebug() << "OpenCV Version" << CV_VERSION;
```

The output I get is:

```
Frame Rate: 1001 
Num of Frames: 610832 
OpenCV Version 2.3.1
```

Which reports the TBR instead of the FPS. This behavior is consistent when I try to open different videos.

I checked OpenCV's [bug tracker](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) and I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352939/opencv-doesnt-report-accurate-frame-rate-count) stack overflow question to be a similar but not quite the same problem, so I am at a loss to what to do next. Any hint or idea is most welcome since I've tried lots of things and seem to be getting nowhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I imagine they chose to report TBR because that is [ffmpeg's best guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199489/meaning-of-ffmpeg-output-tbc-tbn-tbr) as to what the framerate actually is. On many containers, the fps field (more specifically `AVStream.avg_frame_rate`) is not available, so it can't really be relied upon.

Here are the comments from the `ffmpeg` source on the tbr, tbc, and tbn fields:

**TBR (ffmpeg's best guess):**

```
struct AVStream {
...
/**
 * Real base framerate of the stream.
 * This is the lowest framerate with which all timestamps can be
 * represented accurately (it is the least common multiple of all
 * framerates in the stream). Note, this value is just a guess!
 * For example, if the time base is 1/90000 and all frames have either
 * approximately 3600 or 1800 timer ticks, then r_frame_rate will be 50/1.
 */
AVRational r_frame_rate;
```

**TBC (the codec timebase):**

```
struct AVCodecContext {
...
/**
 * This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
 * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
 * time base should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be 1.
 * decoding: set by libavformat
 * encoding: set by libavformat in av_write_header
 */
AVRational time_base;
```

**TBN (the stream (container) timebase):**

```
struct AVStream {
...
/**
 * This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
 * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
 * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
 * identically 1.
 * - encoding: MUST be set by user.
 * - decoding: Set by libavcodec.
 */
 AVRational time_base;
```

Hopefully, that explains why TBR is reported instead of FPS. It appears `ffmpeg` is having difficulty determining the time base for your video stream, and the container (e.g., AVI, MP4, DivX, XviD, etc...) supplies the framerate, so `ffmpeg` displays it even though it can't determine it through analysis. Is it possible to re-encode the video properly?

Comment: Re-encoding the video, although doable, would be a hassle since the videos are quite a few and are somewhat long. They are generated from a Network camera. But your answer gave a clear explanation why I get TBR instead of FPS. Thanks!