# How to free memory after a dynamic allocation of a vector of cv::Mat elements on OpenCV 4.0.0 in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, memory-management, ubuntu-18.04

I used OpenCV 2.4 with Qt 5.7 for a while and allocating those arrays dynamically was a quite simple task:

```
cv::Mat vector[n] = cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_8UC3);
```

allocated dynamically a vector called `vector` with `n` `cv::Mat` elements starting them as zero matrices. I could easily access any `cv::Mat` in the vector by `vector[k]`, giving a position `k`. Whenever they were not needed, C++ automatically deleted them and released their memory.

With OpenCV 4.0.0 and Qt 5.9, if I try to compile this code, I get `array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`, and I figured out ([C++ error: "Array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329324/c-error-array-must-be-initialized-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer)) that I have to start the vector using braces like `cv::Mat vector[n] = {cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_8UC3)};` in order *to compile*. Probably, a new C++ standard (maybe C++ 11 instead of C++ 99?). However, it does not work, because the vector is no longer dynamically allocated, but rather statically. So, the resulting length of `vector` is the size I pre declared as the `int n`, equal to 1, in my code. But it changes to some other value in runtime.

An option that works for declaring the vector dynamically was:

```
std::vector <cv::Mat> vect(n, cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_8UC3))
```

where `int h` and `int w` are the matrix dimensions. But this is actually only creating instances, pointers which are pointing to the same matrix in the memory. So, if I change one, all positions `vect[k]` change.

I found on [OpenCV - Creating an Array of Mat Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138537/opencv-creating-an-array-of-mat-objects) and I could allocate a vector dynamically creating copies of the matrices. I wrote:

```
cv::Mat mat_zeros = cv::Mat::zeros(h, w, CV_8UC3);
std::vector <cv::Mat> vect;
for (int k = 0; k < tracks_count; k++)
{
    vect.push_back(mat_zeros.clone());
}
```

It seemed perfect, I got a `vect` of different matrices `cv::Mat`. But now I notice in runtime that the used RAM memory gets higher until I get stack overflow. After researching around I tried to call `img_buffer_sep_tracks[k].release();` or `img_buffer_sep_tracks[k].~Mat();`, (https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ae48d4913285518e2c21a3457017e716e , http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/) after using it, to call `vect.clear();` after using the whole vector, tried `vect.clear();` and `vect.swap(std::vector<cv::Mat>(vect));` together (["Right" way to deallocate an std::vector object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054567/right-way-to-deallocate-an-stdvector-object)) with no success. Still getting RAM overflow.

Why did C++ or OpenCV get worse in the newer versions? And how to free this memory, then?

Comment: push_back and clear should work if there are no other usages of the cv::Mat data left.

Comment: Problem is quite likely in your code, please provide a [mcve] that reproduces it. | Given that OpenCV 4.0.0 has not been released yet, you're probably using some random revision of the in-development master branch. Unless working on OpenCV itself, it may be wise to use a stable release.